# How can I triple boot operating systems?

Tags: operating-systems, multiboot

I hope this isn't a stupid question, but I'm trying to load Retropie, Raspbian, and really any variant of Kodi/XBMC, all onto one SD card

Using Berryboot, I wasn't able to do much(it didn't recognize my WiFi adapter), so I'll be trying to add all 3 onto NOOBS, if possible

But is there any tutorial or guide on how to do this with NOOBS?

Comment: What about creating all the partitions, installing all that and then setting up GRUB boot menu?? I mean, there is no automated way but there are ton of tutorials. Search for GRUB boot menu, that should lead you in the correct direction.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need 3 boots to do this. You can load Raspbian on sd card, then install RetroPie on it with autoboot and install Kodi in RetroPie (Section experimental packages).

If you want use RetroPie just boot.

If you want use Kodi just select it from RetroPie menu.

If you want use Raspbian just close emulation station and run lightdm with command:

`sudo systemctl lightdm start`

Comment: I still don't get it

Comment: Simple: Install Raspbian on your sdcard. Then download RetroPie-Installer from https://github.com/RetroPie/RetroPie-Setup/ and run. Inside RetroPie-Setup install first RetroPie then using experimental packages install kodi. In setup check to autoboot RetroPie. You will always boot into RetroPie and in menu will be Kodi. If you want to use Raspbian just quit emulation station and run lightdm to use GUI.

Comment: If I switch my SD card from a Pi A to a Pi 3, will it still work?

Comment: You will need to perform `sudo apt-get update apt-get dist-upgrade rpi-update` but I don't know it will boot.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this site: http://www.multibootpi.com/builds/retropie-v4-0-2-raspbian-kodi-libreelec-openelec-or-osmc-you-decide/#more-211

That does not explain how it was done, but at least provides a point of reference.  I suspect it is similar to this method:

- http://bobbyromeo.com/technology/triple-boot-raspberry-pi-on-usb-raspbianretropieopenelec-part-1/

Based on NOOBS (which is multi-boot).

Comment: In keeping with [our policy regarding informationless link-only answers](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538), if this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi flavoured corner of the Stack Exchange Network.  This, along with the other SE sites tries to provide meaningful answers to the questions posed and although those links might indeed have something useful to say on the subject if they should disappear or get moved the information is lost to us here.  As one of our moderators has pointed out if you are not willing to provide something like a summary of what those links say here your answer will be thrown open to anyone to edit _and you will not get any reputation from providing even (IMHO) the starting point!_

Comment: ... OTOH if you can provide useful details here yourself, including perhaps highlight point from the links you give, your answer is more likely to get "up" votes (which are NOT obtainable from "Community Wiki"ised Answers) which increases your "reputation", suggests to other users that your answers are worth reading, and unlocks features on the site for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was successfully able to load Berryboot and connect it to internet in my first attempt. I used Raspberry Pi 3 which has on board wifi. But I preferred direct internet Ethernet connection from my laptop after bridging it with my Wifi connection in laptop for more connection stability.

step 1: bridge your wifi connection of your laptop with Ethernet connection to RPi

https://www.hackster.io/Anwaarullah/sharing-wifi-with-raspberry-pi-using-a-lan-cable-ae1f44

step 2: Follow this video instruction to Multi-boot with BerryBoot

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGCeLct5SUg

Comment: HowToGeek instruction on multiboot

http://www.howtogeek.com/141325/how-to-multi-boot-your-raspberry-pi-with-berryboot/